# Webservice Magento integration with SUPPLIER CROSS DOCKING

Tags: web-services

I am trying to connect my magento to WEBSERVICE my Supplier
but I have no knowledge of how to
Make an import of vendor inventory of products and connect applications approved so called CROSS DOCKING

My supplier casette following date has the SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2

http://wspub.allnations.com.br/wsIntEstoqueClientes/ServicoReservasPedidosExt.asmx?op=RetornarListaProdutos

Integrating the stock with my supplier of my store for webservice connection
I have these data given by more Supplier do not know what to do

http://wspub.allnations.com.br/wsIntEstoqueClientes/ServicoReservasPedidosExt.asmx/RetornarListaProdutos

thanks for help!